# Asp.net Web.config Transformation insert for Entity Framework section

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a web.config file settings that include entity framework section.

Web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>        
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

But I want to use database initializer while debugging. So I want to use entity framework section in `Web.Debug.config` file.

Web.Debug.config file with `xdt:Transform="Insert"`:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <context type="MyProject.DashboardContext, MyProject.Data">
        <databaseInitializer type="MyProject.ContexttInitializer, MyProject.Data"></databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
```

But this does not run the `ContexttInitializer` class. If I add this section in Web.config file it runs.

Comment: You can right click on the Web.Debug.config in Visual Studio Solution Explorer and test the transformation, confirm that the context element is being inserted into your transformed web.config

Comment: When you say you want to use the debug transform, are you deploying the site to a debug server or just pressing F5 to run the app?

Comment: Yes debigging with F5. Does settings are true?

Comment: VS doesn't apply transforms, it will only use the base `web.config` file.

Comment: In this stuation I will add transformation Remove in Web.Release.config does it true?

Comment: Yes, that will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't use the debug configuration transform, it will only use the base `web.config` file. What you need to do is add the Entity Framework configuration to the base file and remove it in the release version. For example, your release config:

```
<entityFramework>
  <contexts xdt:Transform="Remove" />
</entityFramework>
```